# error with string format operator %

Tags: python, string

Been researching this for a while now and can't seem to find a solution. I'm starting to think that there may not be one. Note, I am still self teaching myself Python, so I may be missing an easy solution.

Here's the line:

```
time = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
 sys.stdout = open('/home/username/logfilesgohere/%s', % time 'w')
```

I'm trying to make the file that stdout writes to reflect the current timestamp as per the **time** variable. This would be easy to do in bash with backticks but I'm a python newb. Also to note that I'm using this in my fabfile for fabric.

Comment: There shouldnt be comma before %, and there should be one before 'w'. `sys.stdout = open('/home/username/logfilesgohere/%s'% time,'w')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply put the comma in the wrong place.  This is what you want:

```
sys.stdout = open('/home/username/logfilesgohere/%s' % time, 'w')
```

This piece of code

```
'/home/username/logfilesgohere/%s' % time
```

will build the full filename string.

Comment: Also you might want to avoid using time as name since it is the name of the time module as well.